# Transactions on my private ethereum blockchain don't work. The balances of the accounts stay the same

Tags: private-blockchain

[image: You can see the balance stay the same even after a transaction.]

I have 2 accounts with initial balance, 100000 and 120000. I tried 2 transactions. The 1st was a 20000 ether transaction from the 2nd account to the 1st. And a 1000 ether transaction from the 2nd account to the 1st. Both of them didn't make a difference to the balance.

Comment: my guess is that those transactions haven't been mined

Comment: Then how do I mine them? or how do I get them mined?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run mining process. Try to run in console the command `miner.start()`
then to stop mining run `miner.stop()`. Of course, the mining rpc api should be activated when you run geth

```
geth --rpcapi="miner"
```

Comment: I can't activate the mining rpc api after staring the blockchain, and I can't start the blockchain, if I start the mining rpc api first. In both the cases, it shows the same error "Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp 0.0.0.0:30303: bind: address already in use".

Comment: just kill the process listening in 30303 (previous geth)

Comment: Today, when I started the network, the transactions were working by themselves. I'm not sure how to kill a process that's listening to a port. My problem isn't entirely solved though. My accounts are showing weird balances. I made a transaction of 1000 ethers from one account to the other and there was an increase of 1650 in the balance of the account to which I sent. But the balance in the other account is fine.

Comment: @KaustavDas this increase i think comes from the mining activity. The account got the reward for mining the blocks so its balance will keep increasing. to kill a process under linux see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux/32592965

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been very helpful.

Comment: No offense, man, but you didn't directly help me . I meant to say thanks for your time.  If I accept the answer, it'll be misleading for someone who's looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: in this case add an answer with your solution and accept it.